# Heroku doesn't update assets modifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using heroku to deploy my app in ruby on rails, but have a problem, when I deploy my app, heroku doesn't update with the modifications I made, before I compiled my assets. I solved my problem in localhost using a simple `rake assets:clean` but in heroku this doesn't solve what I make to back update when I modify my assets

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```

Changed this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few things to do. The first is to redeploy

```
$ rake assets:clean
$ rake assets:precompile
$ git add .
... deploy to heroku
```

If it still doesnt work, it could be a caching issue, in which case, you can manually bump the version in `config/application.rb` and redeploy to expire all the previous assets

Ex:

```
config.assets.version = '1.2' # change to '1.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Heroku will pre-compile the assets for you when you deploy the app without assets as it will not find the **manifest.yml.** in assets.

To Make this work.

Remove all the assets files from the public folder in from local and heroku.

**In production.rb**

Make sure you have these code.

```
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.compile = false
```

Set the assets.compile = true if you want the rails app to find asset for you if any asset is found. in precompiled. Ideally this option should be false.

```
  config.assets.compile = true
```

Push these clean changes to heroku.

Comment: I make this but the assets continous not modifying in heroku, i use before the command to compile my assets in heroku and in my localhost, in localhost i issue whit the `assets:clean` but the heroku dont modify the assets.

Comment: try `heroku run rake assets:clean` it will clean the assets on heroku. then push the changes without `public/asets`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue late last night, i found that after pushing to heroku it was disconnecting from git.  Once I went through the GIT process again then pushed it to heroku everything updated.  Not sure why it disconnects, but this has been my work around all day.  Spent 2-3 hours trying to fix the root issue, but the work around is just faster.